# How to get the API provided record values within <Edit>?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have an ArrayInput within an Edit view.

```
    <Edit undoable={false} {...props} title={<AdTitle />} >
        <TabbedForm>
            <FormTab label="summary">
                <ArrayInput source="siteads" addLabel={false}>
                    <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd>
 { record.status === 0 && <TextInput label="Hivatkozas" source="href" props={{ disabled: true }}/> }
                    </SimpleFormIterator>
                </ArrayInput>
            </FormTab>
        </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
```

How can I get the record's fields/values within the Edit view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here will also work FormDataConsumer, an example from the documentation:

"You're using a FormDataConsumer inside an ArrayInput and you did not called the getSource function supplied by the FormDataConsumer component. This is required for your inputs to get the proper source"

```
<ArrayInput source="users">
  <SimpleFormIterator>
    <TextInput source="name" />
    <FormDataConsumer>
        {({
            formData, // The whole form data
            scopedFormData, // The data for this item of the ArrayInput
            getSource, // A function to get the valid source inside an ArrayInput
            ...rest,
        }) =>
            scopedFormData.name ? (
                <SelectInput
                    source={getSource('role')} // Will translate to "users[0].role"
                    choices={['admin', 'user']}
                    {...rest}
                />
            ) : null
        }
    </FormDataConsumer>
  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```